# The column name created was not found in the ResultSet Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 SET message = null FROM (SELECT * FROM einvoice_message 
where created < :created ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS e2 WHERE 
e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<EinvoiceMessage> deleteEinvoiceMessageContent(@Param("created") OffsetDateTime created, 
@Param("limit") int limit);
```

I have this query executed in postresql but receive `SqlExceptionHelper - The column name created was not found in this ResultSet.` Is that supposed to be `e1.created` or `e2.created`? But if so, I'm not sure why, could someone please explain the cause and the fix to this issue?

This is the query for better readability:

```
UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 
  SET message = null 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM einvoice_message 
  where created < :created 
  ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit 
  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
) AS e2 
WHERE e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id 
RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id
```

What's strange is that I can execute this script via query tool, and everything works fine. But the error in log clearly states:

`SqlExceptionHelper - The column name created was not found in this ResultSet.`

Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query;

```
SQL [UPDATE einvoice_message AS e1 SET message = null FROM (SELECT * FROM einvoice_message where created < ? 
ORDER BY ? LIMIT ? FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS e2 WHERE e1.einvoice_message_id = e2.einvoice_message_id RETURNING e1.einvoice_message_id];

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

My table ddl:

```
create table einvoice_message
(
    einvoice_message_id bigserial not null
        constraint einvoice_message_pk
            primary key,
    message bytea not null,
    created timestamp default now() not null
);
```

Comment: Share your table ddl please.

Comment: @FrankieDrake added to my question

Answer (score 0):

Your order by is subtly incorrect

```
ORDER BY :created
```

Order by requires a *column name* not a value. You should have

```
ORDER BY created
```